# How do I make my child theme re-apply the settings that were customised when its parent was active?

Tags: customization, child-theme

### Scenario

1. Pick 2015 theme. Customize various settings, such as background picture, header picture, site name and tagline.
2. But don't touch the contents of any of the theme's files.
3. Use [Codex' Child Themes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to create a bare minimum child theme of the 2015 theme.
4. Activate the new child theme.

### Oops?

The site with this bare minimum child theme activated looks completely different from the parent theme. Background and header image were gone, and all manner of sidebar (or header) widgets had been activated that were not active (by default) in the parent 2015 theme.

Original look of the site with just a few customised settings for the 2015 theme:

[image: SofietjeWonders with customised 2015 theme]

The site as it looks with the 2015 theme derived child theme, which has just the required header in `style.css` and only enqueues the styles as suggested by the Child Theme page of the Codex in its `function.php`.

[image]

### Question

**How do I make it so that activating the child theme keeps the customisations and defaults of the parent theme?**

In this case: the header and background pictures and the removal (deactivation?) of the default (sidebar/header) widgets.

---

Notes

[Create a child theme of an already heavy customised theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/174055/create-a-child-theme-of-an-already-heavy-customised-theme) may sound like a duplicate, but that is about customisations by editing the theme's files.

This question [When activating a child theme, what core settings have to be reset ie; Custom Menus etc?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126324/when-activating-a-child-theme-what-core-settings-have-to-be-reset-ie-custom-me) seem to ask exactly what I seem to be after. Unfortunately, the only answer speculates about a mismatch in features, which is not the case for me and didn't pick up on the OP's comment to the same effect.

I also looked at

- [When activating a child theme, what core settings have to be reset ie; Custom Menus etc?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/126324/when-activating-a-child-theme-what-core-settings-have-to-be-reset-ie-custom-me). It is related, but it doesn't answer my question.
- This: 
  [Register theme customizer settings when theme activates [duplicate]](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116873/register-theme-customizer-settings-when-theme-activates) also seems related, but doesn't address what I want.
- Nor does the question it was marked a duplicate of: [Settings API enable default settings on theme install?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/116873/register-theme-customizer-settings-when-theme-activates) which is about saving the child theme's settings, not about re-using or re-applying the parent theme's settings for the child.

Answer (score 12):

I gave a +1 to the [@webtoure's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/198127/35541) because it gives you the right direction, however I think it lacks some checks.

First of all it does not check that the theme that's being activated is a child theme, and does not check that the theme previously active is the parent theme of the child theme being activated.

Per my understanding of OP these conditions are required.

Moreover, one issue that you need to take into account is what to do with the theme mods of the child theme being activated, if they already exist.

In @webtoure answer, they are stored in a backup, that might save you under some circumstances, but WordPress will not recognize them by default and so they require some additional code to be used.

I think it would be better, to inherit the theme modifications from parent theme only **the first time** a child theme is activated.

In short, the conditions I want to check before to inherit theme mods from parent theme are:

- the previously active theme must be the parent of the child theme that is being activated
- the child theme that is being activated has to never been activated before

To ensure the second condition I'll use a custom option, because WordPress does not provide a way to do this check.

This is the code, please read inline comments for explanation of what is going on:

```
add_action( 'switch_theme', function( $new_name, \WP_Theme $new_theme ) {

    // get the previously active theme
    $previous = get_option( 'theme_switched', -1 );

    // get the parent of current theme, will be false if no parent
    $parent = $new_theme->parent() ? $new_theme->get_template() : false;

    // current stylesheet name
    $stylesheet = get_option( 'stylesheet' );

    // has the theme being activated ever been activated before?
    $lastActive = get_option( $stylesheet . '_last_active', false );

    // if previouly active theme is the parent of the the child theme being activated
    // and it has never been activated before..
    if ( ! $lastActive && $parent === $previous ) {

        // update "last_active" option so following code won't run again for this theme
        update_option( $stylesheet . '_last_active', current_time( 'timestamp', 1 ) );

        // get the theme mods of the parent
        $previousMods = get_option( 'theme_mods_' . $parent, array() );

        // inherit current theme mods from parent theme mods
        update_option( 'theme_mods_' . $stylesheet, $previousMods );
    }

}, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Your first point of concerned is not really justified: if the current theme is not a child theme then `get_template` will simply return the current theme's dir name. You don't need to know the relation between the previously active theme and the current one: if the theme has a parent it loads those settings otherwise it just loads its own settings. I agree though with your second point which addresses the issue of settings being overwritten.

Comment: Furthermore, what if the user accidentally activates another theme before activating the desired child theme? The code will not work and the (`theme_switched`, `current_theme`) relation is irrelevant to begin with.

Comment: @webtoure Your A was fine, I +1 it, the mine wasn't a critic. I added that part because it seemed to me that OP wanted to work in like that. Am I wrong? It happen :) Moreover seemed reasonable to me to avoid to inherit settings from a theme that may not be used since a long time (and whose settings may not be valid anymore) and activate a theme by accident isn't something that is going to happen often, IMO. But again, I offered a solution that people freely change per their needs because answers aren't only for who asked the Q, but also for any other person that might read it in the future.

Comment: I too "+1" your answer for the second part, the first part just seemed strange and unnecessary especially since you've made it sound a bit like an absolute truth ('First of all it [...]') :). Regarding loading expired settings, I don't quite see how your code prevents that? Also if you admit that activating another theme (instead directly the child theme) is not going to happen often then checking if the previous theme is indeed the parent doesn't make sense even more. We are programmers which means we are thorough, logical and analytical. We don't criticize, we just observe. :)

Comment: Hiya you two. Thanks for both your answers. The discussion between the two of you helped clarify the code in @webtoure 's answer, especially the "will simply return the current theme's dir name". Yay. So happy with revision history. Seeing webtoure's version with a backup of the child theme's options made me realize there was another avenue to pursue: retrieve the modifications of the parent and the child, then re-apply both in parent-child order. I think I then don't need to keep track of "lastActive".

Comment: @MarjanVenema I'll be very happy if you'll give bounty to **webtoure**.

Comment: That's kind, gmazzap. Will keep it in mind. Did specifically ask for explanations though and only got them in comments thanks to your suggestions. By the way, my idea of (re)applying both parent and child modifications didn't work. The background image for the child theme did override the one from the parent, but any option not explicitly set in the child theme still overrides the parent with the default. Bummer. Ah well...

Comment: @MarjanVenema gmazzap actually provided comments for his thought process and also suggested a correction to my snippet. I think if anybody deserves the bounty, it's him. Also, I don't answer questions for completely useless points. I love: interacting with people, challenges and generally helping when I can.

Comment: @webtoure Actually, my comment about lack of comments was in regard to your answer ;) Anyways, I already got the impression that both of you prefer answering and interacting over points. Yay! That is my attitude on SO (delphi tag) as well. I'll toss a coin then, shall I?

Comment: @MarjanVenema It was obvious you were referring to me, I simply underlined again that in contrast to myself he **actually provided comments**. I deleted my answer so that you won't have any more dilemmas in terms of who to award the bounty to. ;)

Comment: @webtoure, sorry, having a cold and a bit dense as a result. Please undo that delete. I was actually using your answer (and the coin toss was a joke)

Comment: Just to clarify for others who stumble upon this @MarjanVenema is the asnwer here complete or did you modify your code to do more or be different?

Comment: Please take extended discussions to chat, comments are not meant for them. :)

Comment: 5 years later, this answer still holds water. You'd think WP would have figured out a way for child themes to inherit parent theme customizer settings by now but...nopers. Big thanks for this answer!