# How to make child theme inherit parent custom theme options

Tags: functions, child-theme, wordpress.com-hosting

It's extremely possible this question has been answered before, but I'm not 100% sure of my terminology.

The parent theme in question is a premium theme. One of the things it does is offer custom sections under *Themes > Customise*. I include an image so y'all know exactly what I'm talking about, in case I'm using the wrong words.

[image: Themes Options / Featured Website Content / Site Title, Tagline and Logo / Colors & Backgrounds / Fonts / Header Image / Menus / Widgets / Home Page Settings / Customer Testimonials / AMP / Additional CSS]

I need to overwrite some parts of the parent CSS, so of course I thought of a child theme. However when I load up my child theme, this menu area reverts to the default WP items.

[image: Colors / Fonts / Header Image / Background Image]

As far as I can tell, the custom part of the parent theme is being loaded through the theme's *functions.php*, which means that it should be inherited by the child theme, right?

I've also tried to track down just inheriting the same settings as the parent theme, since for an interim solution that will work.

[See this post here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/196703/how-do-i-make-my-child-theme-re-apply-the-settings-that-were-customised-when-its), which offers a solution to do just that. No joy there either though.

Does anyone have any ideas about what I should be pursuing to work this out?

**EDIT**: *Child themes DO NOT inherit parents Customizer Options*

Incidentally this is a site on WordPress.com, rather than self-hosted. First time I've dealt with WordPress.com so I'm not sure if that's significant or not.

Comment: You need to take it up with the theme author and/or .com support.

Comment: Aren't questions about WordPress.com specific to WordPress?

Comment: Not necessarily. This exchange is for questions regarding developing with or on the WordPress software. This issue is with the specific parent theme you're using, which WordPress.com is responsible for. 3rd-party themes and plugins are off-topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am advised by WordPress.com support that this is a known bug and they are still working on fixing it as an issue.

Currently they suggest a manual workaround to overwrite the unwanted parent theme styles.